# Show that $l^2$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

> Let $l^2$ be the space of square summable sequences with the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$.
>   (a) show that $l^2$ is H Hilbert space.

To show that it's a Hilbert space I need to show that the space is complete. For that I need to construct a Cauchy sequence and show it converges with respect to the norm. However, I find it confusing to construct a Cauchy sequence of sequences?

Comment: Some related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147446/completeness-of-ell2-space, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711075/understanding-a-proof-for-why-ell2-is-complete (Probably more posts about this can be found.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this answer, I will use $x_n$ as a sequence in $l^2$ and write $x_n(k)$ as the $k$-th member of that sequence.

The norm in the Hilbert space is given by $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$. We wish to show that if a sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset l^2$ is Cauchy, then it converges in $l^2$.

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is such a Cauchy sequence. Let $\{ e_k \}$ be the collection of sequences for which $e_k(i) = 1$ if $i=k$ and zero if $i\neq k$.

Then $\langle x_n, e_k \rangle = x_n(k)$. Notice that $$|x_n(k) - x_m(k)| = |\langle x_n - x_m, e_k \rangle| \le \|x_n-x_m\| \| e_k\| = \|x_n-x_m\|$$ for all $k$ (also note that this convergence is uniform over $k$). Therefore the sequence of real numbers given by $\{x_n(k)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy for each $k$, and thus converges. Call the limit of this sequence $\tilde x(k)$.

Let $\tilde x = (\tilde x(k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. We wish to show that $\tilde x \in l^2$.

Consider $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\tilde x(k)|^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(k)|^2=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_n(k)|^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|^2.$$

The exchange of limits is justified, since the convergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(k)$ is uniform over $k$. Finally, since $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy, the inequality, $$| \|x_m\| - \|x_n\| | < \| x_m - x_n\|$$ implies that $\|x_n\|$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, and so $\|x_n\|$ converges. Thus $\tilde x$ is in $l^2$.

---

Edit: Completing the proof as per the comments.

We have thus shown that $\tilde x$ is in $l^2$. $\tilde x$ is the most likely candidate for the Cauchy sequence to converge to, and it has been demonstrated to be in our space. What remains is to show that $$\| x_n - \tilde x\| \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

We will utilize a generalized form of the dominated convergence theorem for series. This states that if $a_{n,k} \to b_k$ for all $k$, $a_{n,k} < d_{n,k}$ and $\sum_{k} d_{n,k} \to \sum_{k} D_k < \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$. (here $a_{n,k}, b_k, d_{n,k}, D_{k}$ are all real numbers)

Writing $$\| x_n - \tilde x\|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_n(k) - \tilde x(k)|^2.$$

We see that in this case $a_{n,k} = |x_{n}(k) - \tilde x(k)|^2$, $b_k = 0$, and we must find a $d_{n,k}$ that "dominates" $a_{n,k}$ to finish the proof.

Now note that $|x_n(k) - \tilde x(k)|^2 \le 2 |x_n(k)|^2 + 2 |\tilde x(k)|^2$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty ( 2 |x_n(k)|^2 + 2 |\tilde x(k)|^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  (2 |\tilde x(k)|^2 + 2 | \tilde x(k)|^2).$$ Recall that we demonstrated $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  |x_n(k)|^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  |\tilde x(k)|^2$ in the first half. Thus $D_k$ is played by $4|\tilde x(k)|^2$ in this case.

Thus by the dominated convergence theorem we may conclude that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_n(k)-\tilde x(k)|^2 \to 0.$$

Comment: When you took the limit out of the sum, you gave a justification. But isn't that always true (property of limits)? @Joel

Comment: Also, in the proof you said "We wish to show that if a sequence $\{x_n\}\in l^2$". Isn't it that $x_n\in l^2$Can $\{x_n\}$ be in $l^2$?

Comment: The exchange of limits does not always hold. You need for one of the limits to be uniform in order to exchange it. There is a theorem in baby Rudin to this effect. The answer to your second question, I meant to type $\{ x_n \} \subset l^2$. My mistake.

Comment: A basic example in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis shows that the exchange of limits takes some care. For example, let $s_{n,m} = m/(m+n)$ and compare $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} s_{n,m}$ with $\lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n,m}$.

Comment: What are the two limits that you have exchanged in the proof? @Joel

Comment: Specifically, this is what happened: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\tilde x(k)|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} |x_n(k)|^2 = \lim_{N\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^N |x_n(k)|^2= \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N |x_n(k)|^2$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_n(k)|^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_n(k)|^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|x_n\|^2$$

Comment: You have showed that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\tilde x$ point- wisely but not in norm. $\tilde x$ is the only candidate $\{x_n\}$ can converge but your proof lacks the part showing it. @Joel

Comment: @denizsargun I'll take another look when I have the time. It's been a few months since I answered this question

Comment: @DenizSargun, sorry it took me so long to write these few lines. I'm sure that you knew how to resolve this yourself, since you spotted the error in the first place.

Comment: @Joel. No worries. I just wanted everyone to have a complete proof on this.

Comment: @Joel, uniform convergence is not enough to guarantee that exchanging the limits won't affect the result: consider $x_n (k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ if $k\leq n$ and zero otherwise. However, since the limit of the norms of the $x_{n}$ exists and is finite, $\tilde{x}$ is square-summable.

Comment: @user115624 What do you mean? Let $f_{n, k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \chi_{[0, n]}(k)$. Then, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n,k} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{n,k} = 0$

Comment: I know it's super late, but could you give some insight for $L^2(a, b)$ space also? @Joel I couldn't understand how to construct a Cauchy sequence from $L^2(a, b)$ ?

Comment: Which result do you use when you claim that the exchange of limits is justified because of uniform convergence in $k$ of $\lim_n x_n(k)$?

Answer (score 11):

Let $(\mathbf{x_n})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $l^2$, where $\mathbf{x_n} = (x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)},\ldots)$, i.e., given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$ 
\begin{equation}
\|\mathbf{x_n}-\mathbf{x_m}\| = \left(\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j^{(n)}-x_j^{(m})|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} <\epsilon
\end{equation}
In particular, it follows that for every $j=1,2,\ldots$ we have 
\begin{align}
|x_j^{(n)}-x_j^{(m)}| < \epsilon && (m,n\geq N).
\end{align}
That is for each fixed $j$ the sequence $(x_j^{(n)},x_j^{(n)},\ldots)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the scalar field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and hence it converges. Let $x_j^{(n)} \to x_j$ as $n \to \infty$. Using these limits now define $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. Now, with this basic setting try to show that $(\mathbf{x_n})$ converges to $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 9):

A typical proof of the completeness of $\ell^2$ consists of two parts.

#### Reduction to series

**Claim:** Suppose $ X$ is a normed space in which every absolutely convergent series converges; that is, $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n$ converges whenever $ y_n\in X$ are such that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|y_n\|$ converges. Then the space $X$ is complete.

*Proof*. Take a Cauchy sequence $ \{x_n\}$ in $X$. For $ j=1,2,\dots$ find an integer $ n_j$ such that $ \|x_n-x_m\|<2^{-j}$ as long as $ n,m\ge n_j$. (This is possible because the sequence is Cauchy.) Also let $ n_0=1$ and consider the series $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (x_{n_{j}}-x_{n_{j-1}})$. This series converges absolutely, by comparison with $\sum 2^{-j}$. Hence it converges. Its partial sums simplify (telescope) to $ x_{n_j}-x_1$. It follows that the subsequence $ \{x_{n_j}\}$ has a limit. It remains to apply a general theorem about metric spaces: if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, then the entire sequence converges. $\quad \Box$

#### Convergence of absolutely convergent series in $\ell^2$

**Claim:**: Every absolutely convergent series in $ \ell^2$ converges

*Proof*. The elements of $ \ell^2$ are functions from $ \mathbb N$ to $ \mathbb C$, so let's write them as such: $ f_j: \mathbb N\to \mathbb C$. (This avoids confusion of indices.) Suppose the series $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \|f_j\|$ converges. Then for any $ n$ the series $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_j(n)$ converges, by virtue of comparison $|f_j(n)| \le \|f_j\|$.

Let $ f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_j(n)$. So far the convergence is only pointwise, so we are not done. We still have to show that the series converges in $ \ell^2$, that is, its tails have small $ \ell^2$ norm: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} f_j(n)|^2 \to 0$ as $ k\to\infty$.

What we need now is a dominating function/sequence (sequences are just functions with domain $\mathbb{N}$), in order to apply the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Namely, we need a function $ g: \mathbb N\to [0,\infty)$ such that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n)^2<\infty \tag{1}$$
$$ \left|\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} f_j(n)\right|  \le g(n) \quad \text{for all } \ k,n \tag{2} $$

Set $ g(n) =  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f_j(n)| $. Then (2) follows from the triangle inequality. Also, $ g$ is the increasing limit of functions $ g_k(n) = \sum_{j=1}^k |f_j(n)| $. For each $k$, using the triangle inequality in $ \ell^2$, we get
$$ \sum_n g_k(n)^2 = \|g_k\|^2\le \left(\sum_{j=1}^k \|f_j\|\right)^2 \le   S^2$$
where $S= \sum_{j=1}^\infty\|f_j\|$. Therefore, $ \sum_n g(n)^2\le S^2$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

To summarize: we have shown the existence of a summable function $g^2$ that dominates the square of any tail of the series $\sum f_j$. This together with the pointwise convergence of said series yield its convergence in $\ell^2$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: This way is new and insightful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pervin = Pervin, W. J.: *Foundations of General Topology*, New York: Academic press, 1964. 
See the proof of Pervin, p.119, Theorem 7.1.2.
All you need to do is replace $H$ in the proof with $l^2$.
The proof is divided into two steps:
Step 1: ($\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy) $\Rightarrow$ ($x_n\to x$) [Pervin, p.119, l.$-$13--l.$-$1].
Step 2: $x\in l^2$ [Pervin, p.120, l.1--l.8].

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Let $(x^n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. We can write $x^n=\sum _k x_k^ne_k$ where $(e_k)$ is the canonical basis. Show $|x_k^n-x_k^m|\leq \|x^n-x^m\|$ so $(x_k^n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, so there exist $x_k$ such that $\lim x_k^n=x_k$ for every $k$. Define $x=\sum x_ke_k$ and prove that $\|x^n-x\|\to 0$.