# Showing a metric space is complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Consider the set $\ell^2$ that contains all sequences of real numbers $(a_n)$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2<\infty.$$
>
> For two sequences $x=(a_n)$ and $y=(b_n)$ in $\ell^2$, define
>   $$d(x,y)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\right)^\frac12.$$
>
> Prove:
>
> (a) $(X,d)$ is a metric space.
>
> (b) $(X,d)$ is complete.

---

So far this is what I've done:

(a)

(i) $d(x,y)\geq0$ obviously, and $d(x,y)=0$ iff $a_n=b_n\Rightarrow x=y$.

(ii) $d(x,y)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\right)^\frac12=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-a_n|^2\right)^\frac12=d(y,x)$.

(iii) Let $z=(c_n)$. We will show that $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Equivalently,
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-c_n|^2\right)^\frac12\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\right)^\frac12+\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-c_n|^2\right)^\frac12.$$

I start by seeing that 
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\right)^\frac12\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(|a_n-b_n|+|b_n-c_n|\right)^2\right)^\frac12.$$

And squaring gives:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(|a_n-b_n|^2+|b_n-c_n|^2+2|a_n-b_n||b_n-c_n|\right)\right)^\frac12$$

Splitting the sum:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(|a_n-b_n|^2+|b_n-c_n|^2\right)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(|a_n-b_n||b_n-c_n|\right)\right)^\frac12.$$

Not sure where to go from here, and no idea where to start on the convergence of an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $\ell^2$, which is needed to show completeness of this metric.

Comment: Instead of keeping the square root, square both sides first.

Comment: Are you saying instead of starting with using the triangle inequality, I should square the left side to obtain $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-c_n|^2$ ?

Comment: I've seen you put thought into typing the math, to make the parenthesis (or any bracket) the appropriate size, use `\left( ... \right)` (see my edit).

Comment: Concerning completeness, take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259364/show-that-l2-is-a-hilbert-space) or follow the links therein.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks!

Comment: $( \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\big)^\frac{1}{2}+\big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-c_n|^2\big)^\frac{1}{2})^2 =  \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\big) + \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-c_n|^2\big) + 2 \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-b_n|^2\big)^{\frac 1/2}\big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-c_n|^2\big)^\frac{1}{2})$.  Look up Schwarz inequality on infinite series to take it from there.

Comment: @Aidan yes. This will be an application of Cauchy Swartz.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially useful remarks:

1) For some fixed $N \in \Bbb{N}$, notice that $a = (a_n)_{n=1}^N$ and $b = (b_n)_{n=1}^N$ are standard vectors in $\Bbb{R}^N$ and the analogous distance is $d(a,b) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N |a_n - b_n|^2}$ is the standard Euclidean distance in $\Bbb{R}^N$. Can you show that the triangle inequality in this case holds (say using induction on $N$). If so, then the infinite sum is the limiting case $N \to \infty$.

2) If $\{(a_n^{(k)})\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\ell_2$, then for each fixed $N$, the sequence $\{a_N^{(k)}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ by the estimate $|a_N^{(k)} - a_N^{(l)}| \leq \operatorname{dist}(a^{(k)},a^{(l)})$. Therefore, for each fixed $N$, there is some value $a_N \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a_N = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} a_N^{(k)}$. Thus, the sequence $(a_N)_{N=1}^{\infty}$ is your candidate point of convergence of the Cauchy sequence.