# Understanding that $A = \{x\in \ell_2: |x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}, n = 1,2,...\}$ is compact in $l_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

I need to show that $A = \{x\in \ell_2: |x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}, n = 1,2,...\}$ is compact in $\ell_2$. I'm given the following hints:

- First show that $A$ is closed.
- Next, use the fact that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$, to show that A is "within $\epsilon$" of the set $A \cap \{x\in \ell_2:|x_n| = 0, n\geq \mathbb{N}\}$.

**Question:** Why do these two steps/hints result in $A$ being compact? (I'm not so interested in *how* to perform these two steps, but more in *why* they would work).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $l_2$ is certainly  $not$  compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) a subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. [The space $\ell^2$ is a complete metric space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259364/show-that-l2-is-a-hilbert-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) Now according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244661/showing-that-if-a-subset-of-a-complete-metric-space-is-closed-it-is-also-comple), a closed subspace of a complete metric space is also complete. Hence the  usage of the first hint. The second hint is used for showing that $A$ is totally bounded.