# Show that the set $A = \{x \in l_2: x_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$, $n = 1,2,\ldots\}$ is compact in $l_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Show that the set $A = \{x \in l_2: x_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$, $n = 1,2,\ldots\}$ is compact in $l_2$. [Hint: first show that $A$ is closed. Next, use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ < $\infty$ to show that $A$ is within $\epsilon$ of the set $A \cap \{x \in l_2 :|x_n| = 0, n \geq N\}$.]

Question:
My main problem is that I don't know how to 'see' the set $A$. What are the actual elements of $A$? Is $A$ the collection of sequences for which each successive element gets smaller and smaller? So that we in fact have sequences $x_{i}$ where $x_{in} < \frac{1}{n}$ where $x_{in}$ is the $n_{th}$ element of the $i_{th}$ sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding that $A = \{x\in l_2: |x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}, n = 1,2,...\}$ is compact in $l_2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498723/understanding-that-a-x-in-l-2-x-n-leq-frac1n-n-1-2-is-co)

Comment: @Test123 That question does not actually show that $A$ is closed or totally bounded, only why those imply that $A$ is compact. So I wouldn't consider this a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you know why the hint is sufficient and so am only explaining why A is closed and totally bounded.

**A is closed** : Let $x \in l_2$ and $ \{x_n\} \in A$ s.t $ \{x_n\}$ is converging to $x$. Then each of the components $(x_n)_i$ converges to $x_i$ ( the $ith$ component of $x$) and so $|x_i| \leq \frac{1}{i}$ for all $i$ . So $x \in A$.

**A is totally bounded**: Fixed an $\epsilon > 0$ . Then there is $N$  s.t $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. now $[ -\frac {1}{i} , \frac{1}{i}]$ is compact and so it can be covered by finite no. of $\epsilon$ radius balls . Let $B_i$ consists the centre of these balls  which are inside $[ -\frac {1}{i} , \frac{1}{i}]$. Then consider the $\epsilon$ radius balls in $l_2$ centered at these sequences : $ \{ y \in l_2 : ( y)_n = 0$ ,for $n$ $\geq N$ and $(y)_i \in B_i$ for $i= 1(1)N \}$. Note this is a finite set and also it gives a finite $\epsilon$ net of $A$.

Comment: So your proof as to why $A$ is closed is: Take a random sequence in $A$ and show that it converges to a point in $A$, am I right? Also, if $|x_i| \leq \frac{1}{i}$ does this mean that all $x$ lie within the unit sphere around the origin?

Comment: I am just using the sequential definition of a closed set of a metric space.. I.e in addition I'm assuming that the sequence converges and then showing the limit is in A....And for your next question.. A is not in unit sphere as the sequence $ \{ \frac {1}{n} \} $ is in A but its norm is pi/ √6 which is greater than 1...

Comment: Hmm oke, so $A$ is composed of sequences for which each successive element moves closer to 0. But as the norm of the sequence is greater than 1 we cannot say that the sequences are located in the unit sphere (even though the individual elements are)?

Comment: @SubhadipMajumder Why are you allowed to conclude that since $[-\dfrac{1}{i}, \dfrac{1}{i}]$ is compact it can be covered by a finite no. of $\epsilon$ radius balls?

Comment: @titusAdam: this is because $[-\dfrac{1}{i}, \dfrac{1}{i}]$ is compact..so first cover it by balls of radius $\epsilon$ centred at every points of the interval..now what can you conclude by compactness?

Comment: How is your last set finite and what is $1(1)N$

Comment: @Abhay, $1(1)N$ means " $i$ is varying from $1$ to $N$". It is just a notation.