# Why is $A$ within $\epsilon$ of the set $A\cap\{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right| =0, n\geq N\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Exercise:** Show that $A = \{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{n},n =1,2,\ldots\}$ is totally bounded, by using the fact that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty1/n^2<\infty$ to show that $A$ is within $\epsilon$ of the set $A\cap\{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right| =0, n\geq N\}$.

I understand that $A$ is totally bounded and I know that the answer to that question was already given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500312/show-that-the-set-a-x-in-l-2-x-n-leq-frac1n-n-1-2-ldots-is). Given $\epsilon$ we know that the interval $[-1/i,1/i]$ can be covered with a finite amount of balls with radius $\epsilon$, centered at points in the interval $[-1/i,1/i]$. Since $A\subset [-1/i,1/i]$ we know that $A$ can be covered with a finite amount of balls with radius $\epsilon$, so that $A$ is totally bounded.

What I don't understand is why $A$ is within $\epsilon$ of the set $A\cap\{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right| =0, n\geq N\}$. If I'm not mistaken, this would mean that $$A\cap\{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right| =0, n\geq N\} = \{\text{$x\in A$ such that the absolute value of $x_n$ is equal to $0$ for some $n\geq N$}\}$$ contains a finite set that is an $\epsilon$-net for $A$. How are we sure that there exists a point $x_0$ in this set such that $x_1,x_2\in B_\epsilon(x_0)$ for $\epsilon = 1/3$?

As far as I understand the reasoning, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500312/show-that-the-set-a-x-in-l-2-x-n-leq-frac1n-n-1-2-ldots-is)  that was given to the earlier question doesn't go into this.

**Question:** Why is $A$ within $\epsilon$ of the set $A\cap\{x\in l_2:\left|x_n\right| =0, n\geq N\}$?

**Edit:** A set $A$ in a metric space $(M,d)$ is said to be totally bounded if, given $\epsilon >0$, there exist finitely many point $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in M$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{i =1}^n B_\epsilon (x_i)$. That is, each $x\in A$ is within $\epsilon$ of some $x_i$.

Comment: What is meant by "within $\epsilon$"?

Comment: @TonyS.F. I edited my question with regard to your comment.

Comment: Yes, I know what totally bounded means. But how is one set "within $\epsilon$" of another set? Do you mean to say that $\exists$ finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A\cap\{x\in \ell^2:|a_n|=0,n\geq N\}$ such that $A\subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B_\epsilon(x_i)$?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Yes that's what I mean. I stated the exercise is exactly like it was in my book. The definition of "each $x\in A$ is within $\epsilon$ of some $x_i$" was also given like I did in the edit.

Comment: But you said that this would make the intersection a finite set, yet what I've written only requires it to contain a finite set. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Yes, I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x_n\} \in A$. Let $y_n =x_n$ if $|n| <N$ and 0 if $|n| \geq N$. Then  $\{y_n\} $ is in $A \cap \{x \in l^{2}    : x_n=0$ for $|n| \geq N\}$. And $||\{x_n\} -\{y_n\} || =\sqrt { \sum_{|n| \geq N} |x_n|^{2}} <\epsilon$ if N is large enough. Hence the distance from $\{x_n\}$ to the set $A \cap \{x \in l^{2}    : x_n=0$ for $|n| \geq N\}$ is less than $\epsilon$. This is what is meant by 'within $\epsilon$'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think I fully understand what you're saying. How do you know that $\|\{x_n\} - \{y_n\}\| = \sqrt{\sum_{\left|n\right|\geq N}\left|x_n\right|^2} <\epsilon$? What would $\|\{x_n\} - \{y_n\}\|$ look like?

Comment: What is the definition of the norm in $l^{2}$? For the  calculation of $||\{x_n\}-\{y_n\}||$ I am just using the definition. For showing that this norm is  $< \epsilon $ I am using the fact that if $\sum a_n$ is a  convergent series  of positive numbers then $\sum_N  ^{\infty} a_n \to 0$ as $N  \to \infty$.